# Firebase: Algorithmic Ranking?

Tags: firebase

Getting started with Firebase and I'm having trouble understanding if something like Firebase is capable of being configured to do things like algorithmic ranking (like Reddit, Hacker News) or if I'd still need an external server for that. There seem to be tons of "Reddit-like" tutorials but I don't see any that go into building ranking, just voting.

If it's possible, what about per-user type rankings like Newsfeed?

Any help would be appreciated.